# Fish shell: how to exit on error (bash set -e)

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling, fish

On bash you can use `set -e` inside a script in order to exit on error:

```
set -e
cd unexisting-folder
echo "this line will not be printed"
```

But on fish shell `set -e` is used to erase variables:

```
set FOO bar
set -e FOO
echo {$FOO} # prints newline
```

What is the equivalent of Bash `set -e` on Fish?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There's no equivalent of this in fish. https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/805 spend a little time discussing what a fishy version of this might look like.

If the script is short, prefixing each line with `and` might not be too bad:

```
cp file1 file2
and rm file1
and echo File moved
```